# To use Markdown as LaTeX's substitute

Tags: latex, markdown

I am trying to write a white paper for my database project by Markdown.

However, I have already had several problems from TOC generation to getting content in A4 -format.

I know LaTeX. However, my small experiment has shown me that Markdown has its flaws to be used in the production of white papers.

**Is Markdown LaTeX's substitute in writing non-mathematical white papers for you?**

Comment: Please s/LaTex/LaTeX/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Markdown** is not designed for publishing of the **LaTeX** class.

Here is a short treatise -- [<del>Markdown Doesn't Scale</del>](http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2007/oct/22/markdown-doesnt-scale/) **(edit: dead link, but [available through Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100203053924/http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2007/oct/22/markdown-doesnt-scale/))**.

I liked the clearly put,

> moral of the story is "use the right tool for the job", or something like that,
> "even when the right tool has backslashes."

> "Because if you don't, you'll just have to blog about it to admonish fellow coders - er,
> document preparers - students? - *people* - to not make the same mistake."

> Yeah, cause I made that mistake. And you shouldn't. Got it? Cool.

---

There is also another question here -- [<del>Markdown versus ReStructuredText</del>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276/markdown-versus-restructuredtext/259048#259048) **(edit: dead as well, [Internet Archive to the rescue again](https://web.archive.org/web/20090116003358/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276/markdown-versus-restructuredtext/))** with this good point,

> Markdown seems useful if you're mainly interested in generating HTML. ReStructuredText (and the related DocUtils suite) is good if you want to generate other structured output formats (eg LaTeX).

---

Having used both of these, I would like to have a small translator that will pickup
Markup and generate the initial LaTeX source file which can be fine tuned with more LaTeX detail.

Answer (score 8):

See [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

> If you need to convert files from one markup format into another,
>   **Pandoc** is your swiss-army knife. Need to generate a man page from a
>   markdown file? No problem. LaTeX to Docbook? Sure. HTML to MediaWiki?
>   Yes, that too. Pandoc can read markdown and (subsets of)
>   reStructuredText, textile, HTML, and LaTeX, and it can write plain
>   text, markdown, reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX, ConTeXt, PDF, RTF,
>   DocBook XML, OpenDocument XML, ODT, GNU Texinfo, MediaWiki markup,
>   textile, groff man pages, Emacs org-mode, EPUB ebooks, and S5 and
>   Slidy HTML slide shows. PDF output (via LaTeX) is also supported with
>   the included markdown2pdf wrapper script.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [MultiMarkDown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) is the best of both worlds. From the short presentation it seems very suitable, but I don't know if it is still actively developed.